# Magento 1.9.2.4 not showing downloader console

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.2.4

I have installed fresh copy of Magento 1.9.2.4 on a custom configured Ubuntu 14.04 LAMP server. While everything is working perfectly, the only error is no status console in downloader. The downloader installs the extension successfully but black status console is not shown and a white space is shown instead of it. Secondly maintenance.flag is not deleted automatically when I click Back to Admin link. I delete it manually. Please guide me what is missing in my server's configuration that causes this error?

[image: screenshot of downloader page]

Comment: Anything in your `var/log` files ? Server error logs ?

Comment: It does not show any error. I have viewed error logs. I am receiving only this error. [client 10.19.0.2:39728] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/bestmall.pk/app/etc/local.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache SSL configuration included Header always set X-Frame-Options DENY. It was blocking the content inside iframe which is used for console on downloader page of Magento. Modifying this option has enabled console.